# C - SHA256 Generation does not output the correct hash?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to generate a hash, but I keep getting different results.

My implementation:

`Pizza is great!` -> `86b01bb0cf966fec8f4864103538359cf5d9b6387ef710e02413a11dcce2e489`

Online generator:

`Pizza is great!` -> `5f5c21c95db335c9e2cedd132e294102a8af08c1ddf81f41c9d54c421cfca1da`

The code I'm using:

I can't use OpenSSL for this project, so I'm using this SHA256 implementation: [sha256.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/master/sha256.c) [sha256.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/master/sha256.h)

```
int GenerateKey() {
    unsigned char message[] = "Pizza is great!";
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE];
    
    SHA256_CTX ctx;
    
    sha256_init(&ctx);
    sha256_update(&ctx, message, sizeof(message));
    sha256_final(&ctx, hash);
    
    printf("SHA256 KEY\n\n\n\n\n");
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if do `sha256_update(&ctx, message, strlen(message));` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, the difference is between using `sizeof(message)` and `strlen(message)`.

`sizeof` declared array (`char message[]`) includes the null (terminating character with the value 0) at end of string, while `strlen` does not include the terminating null.

See this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char message[] = "Pizza is great!";
    printf("sizeof(message) is %ld\n", sizeof(message));
    printf("strlen(message) is %ld\n", strlen(message));

    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
sizeof(message) is 16
strlen(message) is 15
```

BTW, it worth noting, that is your declare the string array like this:

`char *message = "Pizza is great!"`

and call `sizeof(message)`, you'll get actually the size of the pointer which is platform dependent 4 or 8 bytes.